# create wcf service for Android client

Tags: android, wcf

How can I create a WCF service for Android client.

Thanks
Ikram

Comment: You'll have to provide more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: The situation is a bit grim because Android doesn't include the Javax libraries, so you will have trouble consuming any SOAP!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a REST client with Android

http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/

You can expose a WCF service as a REST service

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx